# SQL Query - Sum of Aggregate above a Threshold

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Suppose I have this table:

| Name | Month | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| n1 | 12 | 2020-12-01 | 7 |
| n1 | 12 | 2020-12-05 | 9 |
| n1 | 12 | 2020-12-09 | 17 |
| n1 | 12 | 2020-12-14 | 8 |
| n2 | 8 | 2020-08-02 | 12 |
| n2 | 8 | 2020-08-08 | 7 |
| n2 | 8 | 2020-08-09 | 14 |
| n3 | 9 | 2020-09-01 | 5 |
| n3 | 9 | 2020-09-03 | 11 |
| n3 | 9 | 2020-09-07 | 10 |
| n3 | 9 | 2020-09-21 | 7 |

What is the SQL query to group by Name and Month (sorted by Date) and once the aggregated sum of Value field becomes greater than 15, then it's selected as one row of the result? value of Date field for every individual Name is unique. For example all rows that have Name='n1' have different date values. This applies for n2,n3,... as well.

Based on above example, the result should be as follows:

| Name | Month | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| n1 | 12 | 16 |
| n1 | 12 | 17 |
| n2 | 8 | 19 |
| n3 | 9 | 16 |
| n3 | 9 | 17 |

Thanks

Comment: How are the rows ordered? Also, what is your database, and version?

Comment: It is not clear how to get this output, because for n1 and 12 the total value of group should be 41, but you have 33. For n2 and 8 you have 19 instead of 33

Comment: @astentx Looks like it's a sort of running sum with reset, then group it on every reset and sum it up, ignoring carry-over

Comment: @all my apologies, i forgot to add Date column, wanted to make it simple but obviously was not clear at all. again sorry for the mistake

Comment: **ANOTHER OBVIOUS MISTAKE** is that you didn't tell us what database you are using. You tagged with both SQL Server and Oracle. Those are very different databases, and there are significant differences between their SQL dialects. And it is very important to know your database version also. I asked this 12 hours ago, did you miss that?

Comment: sorry @mathgu. database is Oracle 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle 12.1 and higher, this task is easy work for the `match_recognize` clause. You could just as easily add more columns to the output (for example to show the first and last date for each group, etc.)

**SETUP**

```
create table this_table (name, mth, dt, val) as
  select 'n1', 12, date '2020-12-01',  7 from dual union all
  select 'n1', 12, date '2020-12-05',  9 from dual union all
  select 'n1', 12, date '2020-12-09', 17 from dual union all
  select 'n1', 12, date '2020-12-14',  8 from dual union all
  select 'n2',  8, date '2020-08-02', 12 from dual union all
  select 'n2',  8, date '2020-08-08',  7 from dual union all
  select 'n2',  8, date '2020-08-09', 14 from dual union all
  select 'n3',  9, date '2020-09-01',  5 from dual union all
  select 'n3',  9, date '2020-09-03', 11 from dual union all
  select 'n3',  9, date '2020-09-07', 10 from dual union all
  select 'n3',  9, date '2020-09-21',  7 from dual
;
```

**QUERY AND OUTPUT**

```
select name, mth, sum_val
from   this_table
match_recognize(
  partition by name, mth
  order     by dt
  measures  sum(val) as sum_val
  pattern   ( a* b )
  define    a as sum(val) <= 15, b as sum(val) > 15
);

NAME   MTH SUM_VAL
----  ---- -------
n1      12      16
n1      12      17
n2       8      19
n3       9      16
n3       9      17
```

Comment: thanks @mathguy, a few lines of code and perfect result. it took 5 seconds for around 40 million records.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way you can do it is recursive subquery in both SQL Server and Oracle.
What do you need is to decide if you need to reset calculation on current step or not.

I still cannot understand the reason why you've removed `n1 12  2020-12-14` and `n2 8   2020-08-09` from the output, but you can do it by removing `and isleaf = 1` from the example below.

Here's the query with comments:
(**UPD**: removed `select ... from( select` and rewritten `reset_flag` calculation for standard SQL recursion)

> ```
> with a as (
>   select 'n1' as name, 12 as month, convert(date, '2020-12-01', 23) as dt, 7 as val union all
>   select 'n1' as name, 12 as month, convert(date, '2020-12-05', 23) as dt, 9 as val union all
>   select 'n1' as name, 12 as month, convert(date, '2020-12-09', 23) as dt, 17 as val union all
>   select 'n1' as name, 12 as month, convert(date, '2020-12-14', 23) as dt, 8 as val union all
>   select 'n2' as name, 8  as month, convert(date, '2020-08-02', 23) as dt, 12 as val union all
>   select 'n2' as name, 8  as month, convert(date, '2020-08-08', 23) as dt, 7 as val union all
>   select 'n2' as name, 8  as month, convert(date, '2020-08-09', 23) as dt, 14 as val union all
>   select 'n3' as name, 9  as month, convert(date, '2020-09-01', 23) as dt, 5 as val union all
>   select 'n3' as name, 9  as month, convert(date, '2020-09-03', 23) as dt, 11 as val union all
>   select 'n3' as name, 9  as month, convert(date, '2020-09-07', 23) as dt, 10 as val union all
>   select 'n3' as name, 9  as month, convert(date, '2020-09-21', 23) as dt, 7 as val
> )
> , rn as (
>   /*Build calculation hierarchy from 1st to last*/
>   select
>     name,
>     month,
>     dt,
>     val,
>     dense_rank() over(partition by name, month order by dt asc) as rn,
>     /*To identify last item in group*/
>     dense_rank() over(partition by name, month order by dt desc) as rn_desc
>   from a
> )
> /*Simulate running sum with reset*/
> , rec (
>   name,
>   month,
>   running_sum,
>   dt_until,
>   rn,
>   isleaf,
>   reset_flag
> ) as (
>   /*Start from 1st item*/
>   select
>     name,
>     month,
>     val as running_sum,
>     dt,
>     rn,
>     case when rn_desc = 1 then 1 else 0 end as isleaf,
>     case when val > 15 then 1 else 0 end as reset_flag
>   from rn
>   where rn = 1
>   
>   union all
>   
>   /*Calculate current value*/
>   select
>     rec.name,
>     rec.month,
>     /*
>       If we need to reset calculation,
>       then use original value,
>       else - add value to running total
>     */
>     case
>       when rec.running_sum > 15
>       then rn.val
>       else rec.running_sum + rn.val
>     end as running_sum,
>     dt,
>     rec.rn + 1 as rn,
>     case when rn.rn_desc = 1 then 1 else 0 end as isleaf,
>     case
>       /*Reset on threshold violation after addition*/
>       when rec.running_sum <= 15
>         and rec.running_sum + rn.val > 15
>       then 1
>       /*Or when there was reset before and current value vuolates threshold also*/
>       when rn.val > 15
>       then 1
>       else 0
>     end as reset_flag
>   from rec
>     join rn
>       on rec.name = rn.name
>         and rec.month = rn.month
>         and rec.rn + 1 = rn.rn
> )
> select *
> from rec
> where isleaf = 1
>   or reset_flag = 1
> order by 1, 2, rn asc
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> name | month | running_sum | dt_until   | rn | isleaf | reset_flag
> :--- | ----: | ----------: | :--------- | -: | -----: | ---------:
> n1   |    12 |          16 | 2020-12-05 |  2 |      0 |          1
> n1   |    12 |          17 | 2020-12-09 |  3 |      0 |          1
> n1   |    12 |           8 | 2020-12-14 |  4 |      1 |          0
> n2   |     8 |          19 | 2020-08-08 |  2 |      0 |          1
> n2   |     8 |          14 | 2020-08-09 |  3 |      1 |          0
> n3   |     9 |          16 | 2020-09-03 |  2 |      0 |          1
> n3   |     9 |          17 | 2020-09-21 |  4 |      1 |          1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5660506a067df1d4c7c4382859ab27f4)* for SQL Server.
And for Oracle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0fe4e014641fbee9f10ba1fe712f3024).

(**UPD**: Previous query is in this *[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c0f4ba5e80c6f56d7edb62a0aec17095)*)

And another way for Oracle with [`MODEL`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2161264) clause. Here we reset calculation with [`CV`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions053.htm#SQLRF06175) function instead of recursion.

> ```
> with a as (
>   select 'n1' as name, 12 as month, date '2020-12-01' as dt, 7 as val   from dual union all
>   select 'n1' as name, 12 as month, date '2020-12-05' as dt, 9 as val   from dual union all
>   select 'n1' as name, 12 as month, date '2020-12-09' as dt, 17 as val  from dual union all
>   select 'n1' as name, 12 as month, date '2020-12-14' as dt, 8 as val   from dual union all
>   select 'n2' as name, 8  as month, date '2020-08-02' as dt, 12 as val  from dual union all
>   select 'n2' as name, 8  as month, date '2020-08-08' as dt, 7 as val   from dual union all
>   select 'n2' as name, 8  as month, date '2020-08-09' as dt, 14 as val  from dual union all
>   select 'n3' as name, 9  as month, date '2020-09-01' as dt, 5 as val   from dual union all
>   select 'n3' as name, 9  as month, date '2020-09-03' as dt, 11 as val  from dual union all
>   select 'n3' as name, 9  as month, date '2020-09-07' as dt, 10 as val  from dual union all
>   select 'n3' as name, 9  as month, date '2020-09-21' as dt, 7 as val   from dual 
> )
> , rn as (
>   /*Build calculation hierarchy from 1st to last*/
>   select
>     name,
>     month,
>     dt,
>     val,
>     0 as rsum,
>     0 as keep_flag,
>     dense_rank() over(partition by name, month order by dt asc) as rn
>   from a
> )
> , rsum as (
>   /*Running sum with reset*/
>   select *
>   from rn
>   model
>     /*When to break calculation*/
>     partition by (name, month)
>     /*Dimension to iterate with model*/
>     dimension by (rn)
>     /*Value, running sum and the flag where we reset calculations*/
>     measures (val, rsum, keep_flag, dt)
>     /*Keep null values out of calculation range to identify last row per group*/
>     keep nav
>     rules update
>     (
>       /*For all sequential numberer RNs in ascending order*/
>       rsum[rn > 0] order by rn asc
>         /*When we still have place till 15 (e.g previous calculation of RSUM
>         is not greater than 15), we add current value of VAL to previous RSUM.
>         Else we need to restart
>         */
>         = case
>             when rsum[cv() - 1] <= 15
>             then rsum[cv() - 1] + val[cv()]
>             else val[cv()]
>           end,
>       
>       /*Again, when there's a place and we are not at the end of partition,
>       we mark the row as participating in another aggregated row
>       */
>       keep_flag[rn > 0] order by rn asc
>         = case
>             when rsum[cv()] <= 15 and rsum[cv() + 1] is not null
>             then 0
>             else 1
>           end
>     )
> )
> select
>   name,
>   month,
>   rsum,
>   dt
> from rsum
> /*Keep only aggregated rows or last row per group*/
> where keep_flag = 1
> order by name, month, rn asc
> ```
>
> ```
> NAME | MONTH | RSUM | DT       
> :--- | ----: | ---: | :--------
> n1   |    12 |   16 | 05-DEC-20
> n1   |    12 |   17 | 09-DEC-20
> n1   |    12 |    8 | 14-DEC-20
> n2   |     8 |   19 | 08-AUG-20
> n2   |     8 |   14 | 09-AUG-20
> n3   |     9 |   16 | 03-SEP-20
> n3   |     9 |   17 | 21-SEP-20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cac6ef7c4313d15a3432760bf1a1820b)*

Comment: I think a recursive subquery is required for this problem, so this is probably the best solution.

Comment: thanks @astentx. The reason that I removed those rows from the result is that query should not select any remaining row(s) that their sum(val) < threshold. In your second query I removed "AND rsum[cv() + 1] IS NOT NULL" and could get my result. Regarding your first query which is based on standard SQL and my preference, I did very minor changes to convert it to Oracle but I still get error"ORA-32042: recursive WITH clause must reference itself directly in one of the UNION ALL branches". It's due to having UNION ALL in recursive call. can you please suggest a solution by taking union all out.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - obviously, you think wrong. I just posted a solution that does not require a recursive *anything*.

Comment: @Bob I've updated my answer: removed `select ... from (select...)` that Oracle cannot consume for recursive query and added the corresponding db<>fiddle link for Oracle also. Now it is ok for both DBMSes

Comment: Thanks @astentx. Oracle version that used Model was very fast, 5 seconds for around 40 million records. I chose another solution which was as fast and only a few lines of code. The recursive solution was very slow, even after 20 minutes it didn't finish. Many thanks for the time you spent to provide such a detailed response.